# IOS App Architecture

Tags: ios, performance, architecture, cocoapods

Developing my first IOS app.

About the platform
1. Consume Restful(JSON) services.
2. Build multiple client apps implementing different features with some overlap.

Architecture
[Diagram for the architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xglj6.png)

Implementation
1. Use CocoaPods.
2. Infra POD/FRAMEWORK housing entire Infra layer and the cross cutting layer.
3. Domain POD/FRAMEWORK housing the CoreData Data model and model classes implemented with the ActiveRecord pattern.
4. Each Feature as a separate POD/Framework. (Single Storyboard + multiple view controllers)
5. Each app declares PODS (Infra + Domain + Feature/s ) needed and creates the necessary navigation flow to access all the features. Handle Auth.

Questions
1. Is this possible ?
1. Am I over-engineering this? Should I start with a simple single folder app and than work towards some structure (It could be the above or something completely different)?
2. Anyone working with such a structure ? Any potholes I should be aware of ?
3. Are there any performance implications ? Does having lots of frameworks impede startup time ? Any steps I could take to mitigate the same.

P.S. : My UML sucks. Ignore any UML related problems in the above model. I just did not know of a simple drawing tool on the macOS.

Comment: Hi, I’m afraid multiple questions in one, and broad „best practice" questions aren’t a good fit for Stack Overflow. Some of them *might* be on topic on http://programmers.stackexchange.com when asked separately but I’m not sure, make sure to check their FAQ first

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to hire a research team, not solve a a programming problem.

Comment: Reuse & DRY are two things I strive for. I will take your comment in the positive sense that I have over engineered the problem. But I always find it easier to throw things out then to make them. So it's time to throw some things out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to try and answer this:

You don't have to start with extreme code separation and different Pods in the beginning. If you structure your code in the correct way you can easily separate the parts as soon as you really need to.
Try to stay true to the following points and you wont have trouble to reuse your code:

1. Dont mix your business logic (netcode, database, data persistency, data processing etc...) with your View Controllers. Try to make separate managers for each job.
2. dont copy code! (if you have to, restructure it and make so you dont need to copy)
3. try to work truly object oriented (create objects for holding and storing data, for requests etc etc.)
4. try to use frameworks only if you have to and only well maintained ones. The best way is to stick to apple's frameworks since you know the support wont be stopping at some point

Comment: Thanks ben for your time and comments. I tried the above structure  and it did work (To my surprise..) like you mentioned it might be too complex for something very simple. Thank you for the suggestions as well. I will surely keep them in mind.